# get the first and second or nth duplicated using row_number() over() in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgres we can find duplicated by applying a row_number over a partition of desired columns as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ITB.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
           COLUMN1,
           COLUMN2,
           COLUMN3
           ORDER BY COLUMN1) AS RN
  FROM INNER_TB ITB
) TB
WHERE TB.RN > 1;
```

However this will output data like this :

```
id column1 column2 column3 column4                          rn
1  random  random  random  different_data_across_duplicates 2   -----> how to get the first observation of the duplicate ?
```

Since `column4` was not included in the partition it may probably have different data across the duplicates based on first three column partition.
I would like to have the data of first duplicate just for purpose of looking into the columns that are different across the non partitioned columns. In a real example these might be many other columns other than `column4`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one thing you can do is, in addition to writing your `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN1, ...) AS row_num`, you can also query the count with `COUNT(*) OVER(PARITITION BY COLUMN1, ...) AS count_num`.

The idea is to filter for rows using `row_num = 1 AND count_num > 1`. This basically means that there are duplicates (hence the `count > 1`) but you want the first duplicate (hence the `row = 1`).

This could look something like:

```sql
WITH data_ AS (
    SELECT
        table.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
            column1,
            column2,
            column3
            ORDER BY column1) AS row_num,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 
            column1,
            column2,
            column3) AS count_num
    FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM data_
WHERE row_num = 1 AND count_num > 1
ORDER BY column1, column2, column3
```

##### Generalize to N-th duplicate

This idea can be extended to the n-th duplicate by adjusting `row_num`. For example, if you wanted the third duplicate, the filter could be: `row_num = 3 AND count > 1` where the `row_num` is doing all the work for you here. Keep in mind that if a particular set doesn't have three duplicates, then it simply won't return this as an option.

Edits: I added another option to get n number of duplicates that satisfy the 'duplicate' condition.

```sql
WITH data_ AS (
    SELECT
        table.*, -- return all relevant data from duplicate rows
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
            column1,
            column2,
            column3
            ORDER BY column1) AS row_num,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 
            column1,
            column2,
            column3) AS count_num
    FROM table
)
SELECT DISTINCT data_.*
FROM data_
  JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM data_
    WHERE count_num > 1 -- at least one repetition is a duplicate
    ORDER BY column1, column2, column3
  ) duplicates
  ON data_.column1 = duplicates.column1
     AND data_.column2 = duplicates.column2
     AND data_.column3 = duplicates.column3
WHERE data_.row_num <= 2 -- first two duplicates
```

Comment: I want all duplicates in the query, not just one or the other; but you gave me a good idea. I can adjust the where cluase to `(row_num = 1 or row_num = 2) AND count_num > 1`. i think a lateral join can also solve this but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I added another query that perhaps gets closer to what you're looking for. Does this satisfy your use case?